TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError while trying to swap USDT to SOL on Solana LP
I am getting this error on NodeJS using Solana web3.js:
/Users/carlosmoralescliment/Projects/raydium-swap/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3957
        throw new TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError(signature);
              ^
TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature 5MqEu2Vv5LY2JN932z6jWher65YbW3zgNNwgcSAz7du37CdBomACFX1XWPcLsHuZzygdCDBmZrvCo7kdJnMeZMHF has expired: block height exceeded.
    at Connection.confirmTransactionUsingBlockHeightExceedanceStrategy (/Users/carlosmoralescliment/Projects/raydium-swap/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3957:15)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.confirmTransaction (/Users/carlosmoralescliment/Projects/raydium-swap/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3768:14)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (/Users/carlosmoralescliment/Projects/raydium-swap/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/utils/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:47:7) {
  signature: '5MqEu2Vv5LY2JN932z6jWher65YbW3zgNNwgcSAz7du37CdBomACFX1XWPcLsHuZzygdCDBmZrvCo7kdJnMeZMHF'
}

The error is coming from this piece of code:
const hash = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, txn, [keyPair], {
  skipPreflight: true,
  preflightCommitment: "confirmed",
});

I am trying to swap USDC which address is:
EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v
Into SOL. Which USDC-SOL pool is:
58oQChx4yWmvKdwLLZzBi4ChoCc2fqCUWBkwMihLYQo2
I am using this way to connect into Solana RPC:
const connection = new Connection("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com", 'confirmed');
const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(
JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(./keypair.json) as unknown as string),
);
The error keeps going on.
What do you recommend me in order to change things so this can work?
Change the RPC? Change the slippage? Change the commitment at the time of the creation of the Connection?
I created a connection with Solana blockchain and was trying to swap SOL into USDC using Raydium pool.
But I'm getting constantly a TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError error and the swap is not working.

Have you tried adding a Priority Fee? You can do it like this:
const addPriorityFee = web3.ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ 
            microLamports: 26000
      });
txn.add(addPriorityFee)

